# xml remove xml namespaces appearing at certain elements

Tags: sql, xml, kml, xml-namespaces

i am trying to produce a kml file from sql server.This code is a small representation of my data.
with xml namespaces, namespaces appear in subquery-Placemark section. i dont want that.

here is my query

```
declare @data table(name nvarchar(100), descr nvarchar(100),loc geography)
insert into @data(name,descr,loc)
select 'New York City','USA',geography::Point(40,40,4326)
union all
select 'Boston','USA',geography::Point(50,50,4326)

;with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2')
select CONCAT('kml_',format(getdate(),'yyyy_MM_dd')) [name] 
    ,'icon-1644-000000-labelson' [Style/@id]
    ,'f000000' [Style/color]
    ,1 [Style/scale]
    ,'https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png' [Style/Icon/href]
    ,(select d.name [name]
    ,d.descr  [description]
    ,'#icon-1644-4E342E-labelson' [styleUrl]
    ,concat(d.loc.Long,',',d.loc.Lat,',0')[Point/coordinates]
    from @data d
```

and result is like

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>kml_2024_01_21</name>
    <Style id="icon-1644-000000-labelson">
      <color>f000000</color>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <Icon>
        <href>https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
      </Icon>
    </Style>
    <Placemark xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
      <name>New York City</name>
      <description>USA</description>
      <styleUrl>#icon-1644-4E342E-labelson</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>40,40,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
      <name>Boston</name>
      <description>USA</description>
      <styleUrl>#icon-1644-4E342E-labelson</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>50,50,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

i wanto remove namespaces at the Placemark section

Desired output:(no namespace after Placemark) How can I do it?

```
  <Document>
    <name>kml_2024_01_21</name>
    <Style id="icon-1644-000000-labelson">
      <color>f000000</color>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <Icon>
        <href>https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
      </Icon>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <name>New York City</name>
      <description>USA</description>
      <styleUrl>#icon-1644-4E342E-labelson</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>40,40,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Boston</name>
      <description>USA</description>
      <styleUrl>#icon-1644-4E342E-labelson</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>50,50,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: You basically need to construct the XML without the namespaces, then add it afterwards using the `FOR XML EXPLICIT` trick. See eg https://dbfiddle.uk/OVziB-qU

Comment: I have no idea why anybody would want to remove namespaces.  The namespaces contain important error validations.  Too many times people deliver XML files containing errors because the schema is not checked and then users cannot use the invalid XML files.  You real issue is the XML file you got contains errors which need to be fixed.